# WSO2: Is there a way to manage subscriber roles for each published API in WSO2?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0, and I would like to know if it is possible to manage APIs by assigning roles to subscribers. For example, can I give a role to a subscriber that allows them to see two APIs, and give another role to a different subscriber that allows them to see other APIs? How can I manage roles in this manner?

Answer (score 1):

Refer the document below. You should be able to achieve what you require.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/oauth2/oauth2-scopes/fine-grained-access-control-with-oauth-scopes/#defining-oauth-scopes-in-api-definition